# How do I enable Alt + middle mouse button window resizing in Xubuntu?

Tags: configuration, window-manager, xubuntu, xfce

As of the 11.10 release I've switched from vanilla Ubuntu to Xubuntu for a plethora of reasons.  Thus far I'm loving XFCE and have nearly everything configured the way I like it.  The one thing that's still got me stumped is alt + middle mouse button window resizing.  How do I accomplish this in Xubuntu/XFCE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Button</kbd> drag.

Comment: Oh hey, that worked! Glad to know about this, but do you know if there's a way to rebind this to Alt + middle mouse?

Comment: There isn't such a feature but if you want to change the key, the xfce Settings manager will have this under 'Window manager tweaks' on Tab Accessibility, topmost entry.

Comment: That lets me change the Alt key to something else. I was hoping to change right click to middle click.

Answer (score 1):

I think Alt+[Middle Mouse Button] is the Key binding used by default on Compiz and I don't know if there's a way to configure xfce to do that, but you can always type Alt+F8 to resize windows using the arrow keys.

Anyway if you want to install Compiz you can put `sudo apt-get compiz` on a terminal, and to run it from the startup copy the file `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml`
 to your `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml`
 directory (if it is not already there) and change the lines

```
<property name="Client0_Command" type="array">
  <value type="string" value="xfwm4"/>
</property>
```

by

```
<property name="Client0_Command" type="array">
  <value type="string" value="compiz"/>
  <value type="string" value="ccp"/>
</property>
```

Comment: What advantages/disadvantages does compiz have over Xubuntu's default composting manager?

Comment: Well it depends on whether you like or not to have more eye-candy on your desktop. I use it because I can't live without the Scale Plug-in (to switch between windows) and the Hot Corners Plug-in (to activate the Scale plug-in and to Show my desktop). Another function that I find useful is the Grid Plug-in to maximize windows or use half of the screen for a window (like you can do on Windows 7). The disadvantage is that you need a non-very-old graphics card and it uses more system resources. But like I said before if all that you want is to resize windows you can always use Alt+F8.

Comment: I tried installing compiz-core and when I ran `compiz --replace` my window decorations went away.  I made sure to set xfwm4 as the window manager in the CCSM as well.  Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use both xfwm4 (because it's a compositor itself). I use the default window manager entry in the CCSM, which will allow you to use metacity themes.

Comment: If you want a theme that matches the default greybird theme just extract the folder egtk in http://www.deviantart.com/download/83104033/elementary_gtk_theme_by_danrabbit-d1dh7hd.zip" into the folder .themes on your home folder (if .themes doesn't exist, create it). And run this on a terminal: `gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/metacity/general/theme 'egtk'`, `gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_font 'Droid Sans Bold 10'` and `gconftool-2 -s -t bool /apps/metacity/general/titlebar_uses_system_font false`. In the first command is either egtk or elementary (I'm not sure).

Comment: Then just try `compiz --replace ccp` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. `Type xfce4-settings-manager` in terminal
2. Then click "**Settings Editor**"
3. Then to the left, click "**xfwm4 channel**", then in the right pane change the value of "**easy_click**"  to Alt (or `&lt;alt&gt;`)

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+mouse right click to move your window.